# How to manually send HTTP POST requests from Firefox or Chrome browser

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, firefox, browser, http-post

I want to test some URLs in a web application I'm working on. For that I would like to manually create HTTP POST requests (meaning I can add whatever parameters I like).

Is there any functionality in Chrome and/or Firefox that I'm missing?

Comment: DHC by Restlet (available on Chrome Webstore) is pretty useful too.

Comment: Make an AJAX call in the Chrome console. No extension needed. This is a good way to make POST requests without the need to grab authentication cookies.
`$.post('/resource/path/')`

Comment: Whilst an add on is necessary, the close is niitpicking nonsense. He was asking for functionality in chrome or firefox , or iif it needs a plugin. That it might require a specifed or unspecified plugin is not the point

Comment: https://insomnia.rest is a dedicated API testing client you may find helpful.

Comment: **HTTPie** - **a CLI, cURL-like tool for humans**: https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie

Comment: The post is closed incorrectly. It does not ask for a tool, but for a functionality in the tools the author already is working with. This way we have to close all questions about how to do this or that on some tool - and it will be a good on-tenth of SO.

Comment: I noticed this feature on **Firefox** when you open the **network tab** and choose a random request you can `Edit and Resend` it which is pretty cool.

Comment: In modern browsers you can make use of the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) which lets you do a POST request from the JavaScript developer console with minimal effort. I am prefering this because you don't need to install a third party extension and especially when posting sensitive data (like passwords) it's recommended to NOT rely on external software. Here is a code snippet how to use the Fetch API: https://gist.github.com/bennyn/ed95ed9edd6ce0d04e7c8d6e6eb1a1f8

Comment: @BennyCode gist link is broken.

Comment: Try this one: https://gist.github.com/bennycode/ed95ed9edd6ce0d04e7c8d6e6eb1a1f8

Answer (score 2811, accepted):

I have been making a Chrome app called [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) for this type of stuff. All the other extensions seemed a bit dated so made my own. It also has a bunch of other features which have been helpful for documenting our own API here.

---

Postman now also has [*native apps*](https://www.getpostman.com/) (i.e. standalone) for Windows, Mac and Linux! It is more preferable now to use native apps, read more [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/why_native).

---

Comment: Make sure to install Postman interceptor plugin too if you want to use your browser's cookies, session.

Comment: You are developing great tools and applications for developer @abhinav Thanks

Comment: People may also find the web version of Postman [here](https://web.postman.co). Installation is even not required.

Comment: Tool might be useful, but a 3rd party app doesn't answer the question, which asks for doing this through Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Not to be confused with [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info)...? *"Postman is a toolchain for API developers to share, test, document and monitor APIs."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen This is the same Postman, just 9 years later on a standalone app. You can read about it on https://blog.postman.com/how-we-built-postman-product-and-company/

Comment: Unfortunately, the Postman app uses a huge chunk of your RAM when IDLE. That's a shame when you just need a lightweight app to send basic HTTP request, with eventually some auth. It is a great app with good ergonomy though.

Comment: Wait... This post is sacred 

Comment: And Postman as we know was born.

Comment: Needs a (free) account. Meh.

Comment: The Postman Chrome app has been deprecated by the author.

Comment: damn... the legend

Comment: You should keep working at it... who knows, maybe this 'Postman' thing will catch on in the dev community in a couple of years time...

Comment: Just realised this is the birth of Postman   

Comment: I was hoping that postman might have an "Send to browser" button, under the good ol' send button's dropdown menu.

Answer (score 539):

[CURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) is *awesome* to do what you want! It's a simple, but effective, command line tool.

REST implementation test commands:

```
curl -i -X GET http://rest-api.io/items
curl -i -X GET http://rest-api.io/items/5069b47aa892630aae059584
curl -i -X DELETE http://rest-api.io/items/5069b47aa892630aae059584
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name": "New item", "year": "2009"}' http://rest-api.io/items
curl -i -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name": "Updated item", "year": "2010"}' http://rest-api.io/items/5069b47aa892630aae059584
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this even though it's a wrong answer to the question: it's what I needed to know instead.

Comment: It doesn't fit the whole purpose, because it cannot attach cookies already set in a browser. For example, you might want to log in to a website manually, and then send a post request. With curl, this would be a huge pain if the login process is handled with javascript stuff

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I can't use single quotes on OSX with zsh and bash, shell is turning into `quote>` mode. I need to use `-d "{\"..`

Comment: Yeah, `curl` is awesome, you almost always already have it on Unix, and it's really lightweight for Windows. No registration or SMS! ;)

Comment: Windows cmd.exe also doesn't like the single quotes, so for my POST I used: curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"name\": \"New item\", \"year\": 2009}" http://localhost:60524/

Comment: I recommend `httpie` as "like `curl` but better" (but still CLI-based, unlike Postman). Edit: Whoops, there's a separate answer for it.

Answer (score 340):

**Firefox**

Open Network panel in Developer Tools by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+E</kbd> or by going Menubar -> Tools -> Web Developer -> Network. Select a row corresponding to a request.

**Newer versions**

Look for a resend button in the far right. Then a new editing form would open in the left. Edit it.

**Older versions**

Then Click on small door icon on top-right (in expanded form in the screenshot, you'll find it just left of the highlighted Headers), second row (if you don't see it then reload the page) -> Edit and resend whatever request you want

[image: Firefox Dev Tools with button "Edit and Resent" highlighted]

[image: POST request body highlighted]

Comment: Is this feature broken for anyone else? When editing the parameters in the "Query String" box, after altering a single character, it refuses to alter the request any further. The only way to do it beyond that is to edit the entire URL/request (which is difficult because it's all smooshed together)

Comment: @Coldblackice Can you post a screenshot or problem steps recorder please? I can edit query string just fine. To add a new query string, I either use &= or just start a new line. To edit, change individual k,v or I just delete and start over.

Comment: If you want a field for the query string (`?key=value`) where you can enter key value pairs line by line, just append a `?` and a letter to the `URL` field at the top and the `Query String` field will show up.

Comment: this does not work in the current version of Chrome

Comment: @dima-lituiev, The screenshots above are for Firefox and I've confirmed it works in firefox version 88.0.1

Comment: I've also confirmed it works in Firefox 88.0.1 - However, in my case, the "Edit and Resend" button is not showing up.  I have to right-click on the request then click "Open in Network Panel".  From there, I am able to click the "Resend" dropdown in the upper right and select "Edit and Resend".  Kudos to this solution going strong years later.  

You even have an option for it to create a fetch() command for the request to use in the console like OP was initially requesting.

Comment: this gives me "415 Unsupported Media Type"

Comment: In the latest version of Firefox, only "Resend" is there instead of "Edit & Resend"!!. I took 5 mins to figure it out that there is no other button to EDIT it.

Answer (score 187):

Forget the browser and try CLI. [HTTPie](https://httpie.org/) is a great tool!

[image: HTTPie screenshot]

**CLI** HTTP clients:

- [HTTPie](https://httpie.org/)
- [Curlie](https://curlie.io/)
- [HTTP Prompt](https://http-prompt.com/)
- [Curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html)
- [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)

If you insist on a browser extension then:

**Chrome**:

- [Postman - REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) (deprecated, [now has a desktop program](https://www.postman.com/downloads/))
- [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)
- [Talend API Tester - Free Edition](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/talend-api-tester-free-ed/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm)

**Firefox**:

- [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rest-easy/)

Comment: also resource test addon https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/http-resource-test/

Comment: Poster last updated 28/06/11 - updates to Firefox means there's no way to launch it

Comment: @akostadinov i am unable to use resource test addon in mozilla the tool does not appear (even after installaion and restart) to me under developer tools in the lastest version of firefox.

Comment: Just tried REST Easy. Uninstalled on the spot: the interface does way too much hand-holding and forces the user into rigid use cases. Not good for API development.

Comment: Tried all suggested above for Firefox but found nothing as handy as _Postman for Chrome_. _REST Easy_, by the way, doesn't handle empty responses.

Comment: I would rather use [curlie](https://curlie.io/) than HTTPie. `curlie` is based on the more powerful `curl`.

Answer (score 48):

Having been greatly inspired by [Postman for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop), I decided to write something similar for Firefox.

[REST Easy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rest-easy/)* is a restartless Firefox add-on that aims to provide as much control as possible over requests. The add-on is still in an experimental state <s>(it hasn't even been reviewed by Mozilla yet)</s> but development is progressing nicely.

[image]

The project is open source, so if anyone feels compelled to help with development, that would be awesome: https://github.com/nathan-osman/Rest-Easy

<sub>* the add-on available from http://addons.mozilla.org will always be slightly behind the code available on GitHub</sub>

Comment: Seems nice, but lacks the ability to control the request body fully. Currently, it offers key/value abilities, but full control of the post body would be nice.

Comment: PUT and DELETE support would win me over. Looks good otherwise.

Comment: @NathanOsman, So is that now a feature or still a planned feature?

Comment: @Pacerier: it's a feature I'm currently working on and am about 90% complete. Hopefully it will be released before the end of the year. There does seem to be a backlog getting addons approved by Mozilla.

Comment: After over a month of waiting, the new version has been approved. PUT and DELETE support has arrived! And in that month, I've also made a ton of other new changes that will show up soon in the next release. (Hopefully it gets approved sooner this time.)

Comment: That is not available anymore, as it seems. (It likely is not a WebExtension and thus not compatible with Firefox >= 57.) This problem is tracked here: https://github.com/nathan-osman/REST-Easy/issues/78

Comment: Not to be confused with [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info)...? "Postman is a toolchain for API developers to share, test, document and monitor APIs."

Answer (score 29):

You specifically asked for "extension or functionality in Chrome and/or Firefox", which the answers you have already received provide, but I do like the simplicity of [oezi's answer to the closed question *"How can I send a POST request with a web browser?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307379/how-to-send-a-post-request-with-a-web-browser/3307401#3307401) for simple parameters. oezi says:

With a form, just set `method` to `"post"`

```
<form action="blah.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="data" value="mydata" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I.e., build yourself a very simple page to test the [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) actions.

Comment: I will add, for the ones that don't know: what you specify as `action` is the resource you want to get (which can include GET-style query parameters), and `value` specifies the POST's data body. E.g. `action="api/ids?name=John"` and `value="hello"` will make a POST request to `<hostname>/api/ids?name=John` with a body of `hello`.

Answer (score 26):

I think that [Benny Neugebauer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797534/how-to-manually-send-http-post-requests-from-firefox-or-chrome-browser/19882328#comment96295065_4797534) on the OP question about the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) should be presented here as an answer since the OP was looking for a functionality in Chrome to manually create HTTP POST requests and that is exactly what the fetch command does.

There is a nice simple example of the Fetch API [here](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/):

```
// Make sure you run it from the domain 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/'. (cross-origin-policy)
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',{method: 'POST', headers: {'test': 'TestPost'} })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

Some of the advantages of the fetch command are really precious:
It's simple, short, fast, available and even as a console command it stored on your chrome console and can be used later.

The simplicity of pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>, write the command in the console tab (or press the up key if you used it before) then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, see it pending and returning the response is what making it really useful for simple POST requests tests.

Of course, the main disadvantage here is that, unlike Postman, this won't pass the cross-origin-policy, but still I find it very useful for testing in local environment or other environments where I can enable [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) manually.

Comment: This worked great to get "unstuck" when I had an app that was caught in a bad state that couldn't be cleared because a bug was keeping the UI locked. Got the user going again till the bug could be addressed.

Comment: Exactly like @SteveInCO, I needed a _native Chrome_ method just to get my user (who can't be expected to have anything besides Chrome available) unstuck as an emergency measure. (Even though I use most of the other tools for my own day-to-day use.)

Answer (score 18):

Here's the [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) extension for Chrome.

It works great for me -- do remember that you can still use the debugger with it. The Network pane is particularly useful; it'll give you rendered JSON objects and error pages.

Answer (score 14):

For Firefox there is also an extension called RESTClient which is quite nice:

*[RESTClient, a debugger for RESTful web services](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient)*

Answer (score 10):

It may not be directly related to browsers, but [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is another good software.

[image: Fiddler web debugger]

Answer (score 5):

You could also use [Watir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watir) or [WatiN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watir#Similar_tools) to automate browsers. Watir is written for Ruby and Watin is for .NET languages. I am not sure if it's what you are looking for, though.

- http://watin.sourceforge.net/
- http://watir.com/

Answer (score 5):

There have been some other clients born since the rise of Postman that is worth mentioning here:

- [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/): with both desktop application and [Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/insomnia-rest-client/gmodihnfibbjdecbanmpmbmeffnmloel?hl=es-419)
- [Hoppscotch](https://hoppscotch.io/): previously known as Postwoman, and with a [Chrome plugin available](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hoppscotch-browser-extens/amknoiejhlmhancpahfcfcfhllgkpbld) as well. You can also [make it work locally with docker](https://github.com/hoppscotch/hoppscotch#docker--) if you want to get funny
- [Paw](https://paw.cloud/): if you are on Mac
- [Advanced Rest Client](https://install.advancedrestclient.com/install): already mentioned as a [Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo), but it is worth pointing out that it also has a desktop application
- [soapUI](https://www.soapui.org/): written in Java and with lots of testing functionality
- [Boomerang](https://boomerangapi.com/): yet another way to test APIs. It comes with [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) integration and it also has a [Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boomerang-soap-rest-clien/eipdnjedkpcnlmmdfdkgfpljanehloah/related?hl=en) available
- [Thunder Client](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rangav.vscode-thunder-client): if you use VS Code as your text editor then you should go and check out this awesome extension

Answer (score 3):

Try Runscope. A free tool sampling their service is provided at https://www.hurl.it/.

You can set the method, authentication, headers, parameters, and body. The response shows status code, headers, and body. The response body can be formatted from JSON with a collapsable hierarchy.

Paid accounts can automate test API calls and use return data to build new test calls.

COI disclosure: I have no relationship to Runscope.

Comment: There is a free tier for Runscope too, it just has a lower limit of request per month and only 1 team member.  Disclosure: I do :-)

Answer (score 3):

The question being 12 years old now, it is easy to understand why the author asked a solution for Firefox or Chrome back then. After 12 years though, there are also other browsers and the best one which does not involve any add-ons or additional tools is **Microsoft Edge**.

**Just open devtools (F12) and then Network Console tab** (not the Network or Console tab. Click on + sign and open it, if it is not visible.).

**And here is the official guide:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/network-console/network-console-tool

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

**Windows CLI solution**

In PowerShell you can use [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest). Example syntax:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:3000 -Method POST -Body @{ username='clever_name', password='hunter2' } -UseBasicParsing
```

On systems without Internet Explorer, you need the `-UseBasicParsing` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [http-tool](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/http-tool/) for Firefox...

> Aimed at web developers who need to debug HTTP requests and responses.
> Can be extremely useful while developing REST based API.

> Features:
>
> - GET
> - HEAD
> - POST
> - PUT
> - DELETE
>
> Add header(s) to request. 
> Add body content to request.
>
> View header(s) in response. 
> View body content in response. 
> View status code of response. 
> View status text of response.

Comment: That is not available anymore, as it seems. (It likely is not a WebExtension and thus not compatible with Firefox >= 57.)

Comment: The link (effectively) broken: *"Oops! We can’t find that page"*

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use postman app, had some auth issues.
If you have to do it exclusively using browser, go to network tab, right click on the call, say edit and send response. There is a similar ans on here about Firefox, this right click worked for me on edge and pretty sure it would work for chrome too

Comment: Option is available in Edge, but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

So it occurs to me that you can use the console, create a function, and just easily send requests from the console, which will have the correct cookies, etc.

so I just grabbed this from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options

```js
// Example POST method implementation:
async function postData(url = '', data = {}, options = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
let defaultOptions = {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  }

// update the default options with specific options (e.g. { "method": "GET" } )
const requestParams = Object.assign(defaultOptions, options);

const response = await fetch(url, requestParams);
  return response.text(); // displays the simplest form of the output in the console. Maybe changed to response.json() if you wish
}
```

IF YOU WANT TO MAKE GET REQUESTS, you can just put them in your browser address bar!

if you paste that into your console, then you can make POST requests by repeatedly calling your function like this:

```js
postData('https://example.com/answer', { answer: 42 })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data); // you might want to use JSON.parse on this
  });
```

and the server output will be printed in the console (as well as all the data available in the network tab)

This function assumes you are sending JSON data. If you are not, you will need to change it to suite your needs

Answer (score 0):

You can post requests directly from the browser with [ReqBin](https://reqbin.com).
No plugin or desktop application is required.