# How do I send 'fake' POST header to a page?

Tags: php, post

I am testing a PHP page which gets some data which was POSTed to it. I want to test it and, although I could make a quick PHP page which could send the data I input, I would have thought it would be a feature of the dev tools in Chrome, Safari, etc or a Firebug feature or a browser plugin? I've been searching but I can't find anything.

Should I just make a quick PHP page, or is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: This may help: http://superuser.com/questions/149329/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-the-curl-command-line-tool

Comment: I always just create a simple html page - no css, no UI magic, just plain simple html - takes exactly 1 minute (ok, maybe 2 minutes for longer forms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your development setup, personally I use raw [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/) via console. Browser extensions have been mentioned at [How do I manually fire HTTP POST requests with Firefox or Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797534/how-to-manually-fire-http-post-requests-with-firefox-or-chrome).

Answer (score 3):

I use the [Simple REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb) Chrome extension for this. Plug in a URL, an HTTP method, some headers, and a body. Press submit and it spits out the response body. If it's a JSON response I use a nice [Pretty Printer](http://www.cerny-online.com/cerny.js/demos/json-pretty-printing) tool.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [modify headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/) plugin for that purpose.  I also use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) for testing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Better use firebug addon  in Firefox

http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Insomnia REST Client](https://insomnia.rest), like so:

1. Select "Post":

[image]

2. Type in the URL and optionally any parameters.
3. Click "Send".

I am not affiliated with the creators of Insomnia.