# Is there a quick way send post requests?

Tags: rest, post, google-chrome-extension

i want to test a small php script i wrote, which accepts POST requests..
but is there a way to test it without writing a html form.
Im trying to do this using simple rest client chrome extension. But I'm not sure how to do POST request in it.

Comment: Did you look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797534/how-to-manually-fire-http-post-requests-with-firefox-or-chrome?

Comment: If switching is an option, I would recommend Advanced Rest Client. It is very intuitive, and I have used it for a year now.

Comment: @whirlwin i can switch.. but can i do multiple post requests? if so how..

Comment: @Charx yes i did see that question. but fiddler is windows only.. and I m not sure how to do the post request in Postman.

Comment: Do you mean sending multiple POST requests concurrently or sequentially?

Comment: @whirlwin say the post equivalent of http://www.test.com?a=fa&b=123

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using Advanced REST Client, you can send a POST request in which the data can be stored as form data (probably the simplest).

Just click the **second** `Form` tab when entering the application, and you can specify key-value pairs.

Here is an image of the application.

[image: Advanced Rest Client]

Comment: oh perfect, thanks.. i will update in a min if it works.. looks like this is what i want

Comment: @syllogismos I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: If you want to read from $_POST (in PHP) change Content-Type header to **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

Answer (score -2):

I use a very nice Chrome extension for this: REST client or similar. Look in the chrome market, is plenty of tools.

Comment: yes there are plenty.. but I dont know how to send a post request using those extensions.. i'm not able to see the post variables in $_POST array..

Comment: can you be more specific on how to test a post request