# Triggering jenkins build over ssh?

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, zos

I'm trying to trigger a Jenkins build from a USS (unix on z/os) git repository. The jenkins server is running in tomcat on my local windows machine.

Most examples on the web describe a solution like this: http://www.andyfrench.info/2015/03/automatically-triggering-jenkins-build.html

and I managed to get that working on my home pc from a local windows-based git repo to my locally running jenkins server.

Basically, this involves creating a post-commit hook and invoking a special Jenkins git endpoint via cURL. The only issue is, my organization did not install cURL on USS, so we have to do everything over ssh.

Is there a way to create a post-commit hook script on a USS system that invokes a jenkins build on windows without using cURL (likely ssh)?

My setup is: git on z/os (commit) -> trigger jenkins pipeline (on windows) -> which does some stuff to build, populate various repos on

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused.  You want the build to happen on the z/OS system, triggered from the jenkins server on Windows, correct?  What is set up on the z/OS system?  For example, can you submit jobs via FTP?

Comment: Yes that's about right. My setup is:
git on z/os (commit) -> trigger jenkins pipeline (on windows) -> which does some stuff to build, populate various repos

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be talk to your sysprogs, and ask them to install the [Rocket Software ported tools](https://www.rocketsoftware.com/zos-open-source/tools) suite, which includes cURL.

Comment: https://my.rocketsoftware.com/RocketCommunity/RCLogin?nextURL=downloads&categoryName=z%2FOpenSource&toolName=cURL

Comment: I am aware of this, however progress is extremely slow so I'm opting for another route as we need to build out some CI for our development pipeline soon.

Answer (score 2):

The Durable-Task-Plugin was recently updated to fix issues with SSH and encoding.  This should help:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Durable+Task+Plugin

> Changelog Version 1.29 (Jan 31, 2019)
>   Enhancement: Add support for z/OS Unix System Services to the sh step. (JENKINS-37341)

Comment: I'm not clear on how durable-task-plugin would help me here. I looked at the documentation and it speaks to monitoring processes outside of Jenkins. I want to just be able to invoke a url from a bash script on zos, triggered in a post-commit hook, and I can't use cURL. It would be good if I could somehow call the existing git Jenkins repo endpoint as it integrates well into the build jobs.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your Windows.

The [latest Windows 10 (1803+)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration), for instance, comes with an [OpenSSH server (beta feature) that you can activate](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/how-to-install-the-built-in-windows-10-openssh-server/).

[For earlier version of Windows](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server), you would need to install an [openSSH server](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases) to listen to your hook SSH call.

Comment: The question is about z/OS USS as the target environment, not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

And a third option would be to use telnet to invoke the web hook, as documented here:  [How to make an HTTP GET request manually with netcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341518/how-to-make-an-http-get-request-manually-with-netcat)