# Set clearcase config spec and update snapshot view that exists on another machine

Tags: clearcase

I need to create a simple script (batch, python etc.) which I can run from my windows machine that will set the config spec and update the snapshot view that exists on some other machines.

Is there a clearcase command that do that ?
Or should I use psexec or something similar that will run the command on each machine ?
Thanks

Comment: Did my answer addressed your question?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

- how to contact and run remote commands on other machines?
  Considering recent Windows 10 come with SSH integrated with [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), or even [OpenSSH server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54879208/6309), you could use that for other Linux machines.
  For other Windows machines, [`psexec` or `winrs`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) are possible alternatives (See also [WMI or ControlUp](https://4sysops.com/archives/three-ways-to-run-remote-windows-commands/)).
  But unless you can open a remote session as admin, you won't probably have access to the snapshot view, which could be created in the Windows User profile (protected).
- what ClearCase command to run?
  Probably [`cleartool setcs`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setcs.htm) (I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12741082/6309) a snapshot view would always be updated after a `setcs`)