# How to query a webserver with Netcat?

Tags: netcat

I checked this [How to make an HTTP GET request manually with netcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341518/how-to-make-an-http-get-request-manually-with-netcat), but it didn't really answer my question.

This is for an assignment and I'm stuck.

There's a client (User), web server (Web), and an authentication server (Auth), which holds the usernames/passwords that Web checks with (and sends out packets with such info that can be seen with Wireshark).

Web has a simple username/password form. I want to query Auth a specific username to see the password through Wireshark.

This is the hint given to us on how to send network traffic:

```
echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1 \n\n" | nc Web <port #>
```

I've tried several things, such as:

```
echo -e "GET / HTTP/john \n\n" | nc Web 80  
(echo "john" ; echo " ";) | nc Web 80  
echo -n -e "john" | nc Web 80
```

and others. I can't find much relevant resources online for this scenario.

Comment: You need to send a _valid_ HTTP request. You're just sending random data.

Comment: @tkausl so what's the format for such a request to include a username but no password?

Answer (score 0):

This is a shell debugging problem.

```
echo -e 'GET / HTTP/john \n\n' | nc Web 80
```

is what you want.

`""` eats the `\` in bash.

Comment: it's supposed to be `\r\n`, like in windows-newlines, also it's supposed to be `\r\n\r\n` which is the magical "end of request headers" string - headers are separated by `\r\n` and the last header has `\r\n\r\n`

Comment: @hanshenrik Yes, but the root cause of the problem is that you can not backslash in a " in bash.

Comment: Perhaps. But a HTTP-specs-compliant request would be ```echo -ne 'GET / HTTP/john\r\n\r\n'``` - edit: forgot `-n`, that's also required to make echo not add a surplus `\n` at the end