# How can i read data exchanged between a client and server in Rust?

Tags: rust, server, tcp, client, client-server

A client sends a branch code to the server.

After the reading `branch_code` action has been done, the server needs to send an "OK", to the client, which will afterward send some data encoded using base64. Here is the how I intend the client-side to operate.

```
match TcpStream::connect(server_address)  {
        Ok(mut stream) => {
            println!("Connected to Server");

            // Send branch code back to the server
            let branch_code = format!("bcode~{}", branch_code);
            let branch_length = branch_code.len();
            if let Err(e) = stream.write_all(&(branch_length as u32).to_be_bytes()) {
                error!("Error writing the length: {:?}", e)
            }
            if let Err(e) = stream.write_all(branch_code.as_bytes()){
                error!("Error writing branch message: {:?}", e);
                // return;
            }else {
                println!("Branch code sent successfully")
            };
            println!("Branch code: {}", branch_code);
    
            // Receive an acknowldgement from the server
            // Reading the "OK" lenght
            let mut resp_length_buff = [0; 4];
            if let Err(e) = stream.read_exact(&mut resp_length_buff){
                error!("Error reading response: {:?} ", e)
            };
            let length = u32::from_be_bytes(resp_length_buff);
            
            // Reading the "Ok" response
            let mut response_buff = vec![0; length as usize];
            stream.read_exact(&mut response_buff).expect("Failed to read response");
            let response = String::from_utf8_lossy(&response_buff);
            println!("1st response: {}", response);
            
            if response.trim() == "OK" {
                // Send base64 content to the server
                let file_message = format!("~{}~", base64_content);
                if let Err(e) = stream.write(file_message.as_bytes()){
                    error!("Error writing file message to stream: {:?}", e);
                    // return;
                };
    
                // Receive an acknowledgement from the server
                let mut response = String::new();
                if let Err(e) = stream.read_to_string(&mut response){
                    error!("Error reading response from stream: {:?}", e)
                };
    
                if response.trim() == "OK"{
                    println!("Sales report transferred successfully")
                } else {
                    error!("Error in sales transfer")
                }
            } else {
                error!("Error in branch code acknowledgement")
            }

            if stream.shutdown(Shutdown::Both).is_err(){
                error!("Failed to close the connection")
            }
        }
        Err(err) => {
            error!("Failed to connect to server: {:?}", err);
            // return;
        }
    }
```

The server  should send the OK message, after reading the `branch_code`, and afterwards read data the sent by the client-side.

```
//server-side/src/main.rs

//previous code of getting the branch_code

    // Send acknowledgment to the client
    if let Err(e) = stream.write_all(b"OK") {
        error!("Error writing acknowledgment to stream: {:?}", e);
        return;
    };

    // Receive Base64 content from client
    let mut base64_content = String::new();
    if let Err(e) = stream.read_to_string(&mut base64_content) {
        error!("Error reading Base64 content: {:?}", e);
        return;
    };
    println!("Received Base64 content: {}", base64_content);
```

What can i do to ensure that all these actions take place. ie, after the code was read, the terminal just stopped, as if to show something failed, the client didn't read the OK message and thus no content was sent to the server. How can i fix these issues?

I have tried reading the length sent by the server to the client, but the "OK" message is not being read by the client, hindering it to transfer the data.

Comment: You probably can use something like [nc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341518/how-to-make-an-http-get-request-manually-with-netcat) while the link is specifically about HTTP it can easily be used for any simple TCP protocol.