# Send POST requests with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http-post

Is there a way to fake POST requests in Chrome?

So far the best Ive seen is the extension called [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) which I think is BRILLIANT except for 1 detail that is critical. It doesnt download the other resources like CSS stylesheets and images.

What other tool I could use?

Comment: have you tried dev http client?
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dev-http-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Comment: That worked awesome. Put it as an answer, and I will accept it :)

Comment: That is not necessary. Glad that I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try use Postman as a Google Chrome App

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

(P.S. from [How do I manually fire HTTP POST requests with Firefox or Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797534/how-do-i-manually-fire-http-post-requests-with-firefox-or-chrome))