# How to simulate HTTP POST on localhost (*Windows* not Unix)?

Tags: http, browser, http-post, localhost, browser-plugin

What is the simplest way of sending an HTTP POST to a **localhost** address/port under Windows?

E.g. do any browser plugins exist to do this or could a command be sent in the Chrome Developer Tools / Firebug console?

[Have seen similar q's asked before but the answers mostly seem to recommend the use of Unix tools such as CURL or Websites such as http://www.hurl.it, which preclude sending the request to localhost.]

Comment: After a few more minutes of searching I found a very similar q has actually been asked before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797534/how-do-i-manually-fire-http-post-requests-with-firefox-or-chrome) so have voted to close.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I use `Advanced REST Client` usually. I assume it works offline too(never tried it though as my Internet is always on).

[Advanced REST Client for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)

I think the plugin is available for firefox too. Just google `Advanced REST Client`

EDIT:

Some other cool alternatives:

[Paw](https://paw.cloud/) (My current favourite)

[Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)

Answer (score 6):

if you use Chrome you can go with the 
[DHC by Restlet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dev-http-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher)
or with 
[Rest Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher).

I think you can find extension like those for firefox too.

Answer (score 4):

I would invoke PHP with a script that does the post.

file `send_post.php`

```
<?php
// here I use argv for URL, but you can adapt it however you like
$url = "http://localhost/".$argv[1];
$data = array('var1' => 'value1', 'var2' => 'value2');

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)));

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($options));

// you can echo the response if you're interrested, or just dump it
echo $response;
?>
```

test file `http://localhost/SO/PHP/receive_post.php`

```
<?php print_r ($_POST) ?>
```

invokation

```
C:\Dev\PHP\SO\PHP>php send_post.php whatever

Warning: file_get_contents(http://localhost/whatever): 
         failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
         in C:\Dev\PHP\SO\PHP\send_post.php on line 12

C:\Dev\PHP\SO\PHP>php send_post.php SO/PHP/receive_post.php
Array
(
    [var1] => value1
    [var2] => value2
)
```

Comment: Well a batch file might be considered simpler than a GUI. It all depends of your definition of "simple" :). Maybe some other OPs will find that alternative more appealing, who knows?