# Restful webservice in Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

I want to access a webservice function that takes two strings as arguments and return a JSON value. I found a solution to do this using volley library but apparently i have to use Android Lolipop for this. 
is there a way to do this without volley? Another library? or httpconnection?
An example of this use will be perfect.

Comment: I would highly recommend Retrofit rest client Library with RxJava. This has been the most efficient way in terms of performance, time of execution, observable and many other. Check them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library http://square.github.io/retrofit/

or using httpURLConnection

```
 HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
 try {
     // create URL
     URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
     // open connection
     httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
     // 15 seconds
     httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
     Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("firstParameter", firsParametersValue).appendQueryParameter("secondParameter", secondParametersValue)
     String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
     OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
     BufferedWriter bufWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
     bufWriter.write(query);
     bufWriter.flush();
     bufWriter.close();
     outputStream.close();

     if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()), 8192);
        String strLine = null;
        while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
           response.append(strLine);
        }
        input.close();
        Object dataReturnedFromServer = new JSONTokener(response.toString()).nextValue();
        // do something
        // with this
     }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do something
} finally {
    if (httpURLConnection != null) {          
       httpURLConnection.disconnect();// close connection
    }
}
```