# Making a simple Web API post request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm really struggling with making a basic post request in a url to support a tutorial on web api.

I want to do something like this in browser: http://localhost:59445/api/group/post/?newvalue=test and get the post to register. However I don't seem to be able to form the request correctly. What is the correct way to do this?

The error I receive is:

> {"Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String Get(Int32)' in 'twin_groupapi.Controllers.GroupController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}

my model:

```
    public class Group  
    {
     public Int32 GroupID { get; set; }
     public Int32 SchoolID { get; set; }
     public string GroupName { get; set; }
    }
```

routing:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

controller:

```
    //[Route("api/Group/Post")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromUri] string NewValue)
    {

        string newstring = NewValue;

    }
```

Comment: Do you have another method with name post and verb as `httpget`?

Comment: only other verb is        `// GET: api/Group

        [Route("api/Group/Get")]
        [HttpGet]
        public Array Get()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hitting a URL in your browser will only do a GET request.

You can either:

- create a simple `<form>` with its method set to `POST` and form inputs to enter the values you want to send (like `NewValue`), OR
- write some JavaScript to create an AJAX POST request using your favorite framework, OR
- Use a tool like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) to set up a POST request, invoke it, and examine the results.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is most likely coming from your Get() method.

As @StriplingWarrior said you are making a GET request while the method is marked as `[HttpPost]`. You can see this if you use developer tools in your browser (F12 in most modern browsers to active them).

Have a look at [How do I manually fire HTTP POST requests with Firefox or Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797534/how-do-i-manually-fire-http-post-requests-with-firefox-or-chrome)

Note: the c# convention for parameter names is camelCase with first letter being common, not capital, e.g. `string newValue`.

Comment: To make this concrete from the link above, read up on the Fetch API as perhaps the simplest approach.  So if you want to do a POST from the browser, just type something like the following in the browser console: `fetch('http://localhost:59445/api/group/post/?newvalue=test',{ method: 'POST'})`