# Codeigniter Not allowing to post data in REST API post method via url. it's showing error like unknown method

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, codeigniter-restserver

I am trying to send data through url like

**http://localhost/api/index.php/society/?date=20/04/2017&s_name=ssr**

but it's showing error message:

> **{"status":false,"error":"Unknown method"}**

When I am testing with `postman` or `advance rest client` application, it's working fine and data is posting and updating database.

url: **http://localhost/api/index.php/society**

***My Controller....***

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php';

use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;

class Society extends REST_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database(); 
        $this->load->model('Society_model');
    }

    public function index_get()
    {
        $data = $this->Society_model->society_get();
        $this->response($data);
    }

    public function index_post()
    {

        $data = array( 
            'date' =>$this->post('date'),
            'society_name' => $this->post('s_name'), 
            'society_group' => $this->post('g_name'),
            'contact_name' => $this->post('c_name'),
            'mobile_no' => $this->post('mobile'),
            'address' => $this->post('address'),
            'city' => $this->post('city'),
            'state' => $this->post('state'),
            'pincode' => $this->post('pincode'),
            'email_id' =>$this->post('email')
           ); 

         $this->Society_model->insert($data); 

         $this->set_response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
}
```

***My Model....***

```
<?php

class Society_model extends CI_Model
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
    }

    public function society_get(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('society_contact');
        $result = $this->db->get();
        return $result->result();
    }

    public function insert($data) 
    { 
         if ($this->db->insert("society_contact", $data)) 
         { 
            return true; 
         } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you think it should be running, as well as anything which would cause it to return the "Unknown Method" response?

Comment: I have poted my codes can you check ? @gabe3886

Comment: Is you `Society` controller stored straight in the `controllers` folder or is it in a sub-folder? Plus you need to URL encode your parameters. Your date parameter  has `/` which is also used as a URL delimiter.

Comment: Society stored in controller not having sub folder. how can i encode URL in parameters? I am new in REST API field development in codeigniter. @ Hicaro

Answer (score 0):

**society** is your model function name ..call it by **index** name 
**http://localhost/api/index.php/index/?date=20/04/2017&s_name=ssr**

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the POST method via a browser. You must use POSTMAN or another REST Client. URL in browser only allows you to GET information.

Please refer to this post [How do I manually fire HTTP POST requests with Firefox or Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797534/how-do-i-manually-fire-http-post-requests-with-firefox-or-chrome)

Also your URL http://localhost/api/index.php/society/?date=20/04/2017&s_name=ssr

it is not correct because when you added `?something=something`, this is a parameter, also if you added **/** this are separate parts of the url. That is why you are getting **Unknow Method**.

Comment: Thanks Bro, There was an issue in Content-Type.