# Pass json object by navigator instead of java

Tags: java, json

I have a java application with this code :

```
URL url = new URL("http://myurl/");
HttURLConnection connection = (HttURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutplut(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
buffer.write("{\"foo:\"0}");
buffer.flush();
```

I just want to do the samething in my navigatour URL bar.

*Edit*

I found a tool to modifier headers. Here a screenshoot of the dev tool when I load my page. 
Now where did I put my Json object?

[image: header request]

Comment: `Content-Type` should be inside header not query.

Comment: And `{\"foo\":bar}` in the body rather than the query parameters. Also that isn't valid JSON, which seems suspicious.

Comment: yeah, it is {\"foo:\"bar}. taht not the important part

Comment: @AniketSahrawat how did I put insided the hearder?

Comment: @JulienMaret You are doing it right in the code snippet. I will suggest you to add `connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");` along with it. It may or may not change the output by server. Also the JSON string that you are trying to pass is invalid. The correct JSON would be `"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to send  `JSON` data to your `URL` your code should be like this,

```
            URL url = new URL("http://myurl/");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            String input = "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}";
            OutputStream ous = con.getOutputStream();
            ous.write(input.getBytes());
            ous.flush();

            if (con.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + con.getResponseCode());
            }else
            {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((con.getInputStream())));
                String output;
                System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
                while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                     System.out.println(output);
                }
            }

            con.disconnect();
```

If you need `GET` Method then you can place this,

```
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

If you need to send Request Body with the URL you can use `CURL`. And also you can use [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/). By using this you can send requests and receive the response.

`CURL` will be like this,

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST \
     -d '{\"foo\":\"bar\"}' http://myurl/
```

You can use `Firefox` to perform what you need, [Read the 2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797534/how-do-i-manually-fire-http-post-requests-with-firefox-or-chrome).

Comment: actualy, it is like this.

Comment: I edited the question. I would like to avoid install a new software, and only use my navigator.