# Calling C# API from Kotlin

Tags: c#, api, kotlin

I have written an android app using Kotlin that consumes an API written in C#. The API method is supposed to return "true" (as a string and not a boolean), and it does. I am using Fuel to call the API.

Everything works fine but when I get the data i get the value as ""true"". Hence (data == "true") always returns false.

What could be going wrong?

Kotlin code :

```
                "abcdefgh"
                .httpPost()
                .body("$firstArg|$secondArg")
                .responseString() { request, response, result ->
                    when (result) {
                        is Result.Failure -> {
                            val ex = result.getException()
                            Toast.makeText(this, ex.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show() 
                        }
                        
                        is Result.Success -> {
                            **val data = result.get()**
                           .
                           .
                           .
                           .
                           .
```

*data* is always ""true"" instead of expected "true".

Please help.

Comment: > i get the value as ""true""

So, you've got extra double quotes surrounding `true`. You can get rid of them with `data.trim('"')`

Comment: Thanks, that helps. But is there a reason this is happening?

Comment: I believe this is the way this C# backend is implemented. To be sure try to call this API with [Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26848256/13968673) or curl. Does it still return extra double quotes?